# A pseudo-Sql server to intercept and see all MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, logging, sql, query

I would like to setup a "pseudo-server" to intercept all the SQL queries made by my local application.

The reason for that is that I can't administer the Mysql server, and it's difficult for me to edit the configuration files to enable any logging. The easiest way would be to have a Sql "router" that would redirect all my queries to the original server, but log them for me to debug. That way I would only have to set the server URL to localhost (and configure the username).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy

Comment: Perfect, a bit tricky to set up, but now it works!

Comment: I also recommend using the following script: http://forge.mysql.com/tools/tool.php?id=80.